# PySide2 remove QPushButton hover style

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside2

i am trying to create a small corner icon on top of an image in Python3.9 using Pyside2 Qt Widgets.
How can i remove the hover style effect?

```
 # Corner button
    self.corner_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self, flat=True) # create button
    self.corner_btn.setIcon(createIcon("TOP_status_cooked", 50)) # set icon to button
    self.corner_btn.setProperty('transparent', True) # make rest of the button transparent

    # remove hover style - these do not work
    self.corner_btn.setFlat(True)
    self.corner_btn.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    self.corner_btn .setStyleSheet("QToolButton::hover{background-color: #ffffff;}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hover style effect"? Also, you're using a QPushButton, why are you setting the style sheet using the QToolButton selector?

Comment: I was talking about the highlight effect when i hover over the button. Changed the QToolButton to "QPushButton{background: transparent; border: 0px;}" and fixed it. Is there a way to make it trasparent to the mouse as well? so that if there is a larger button behind i can press it?

Comment: If you don't want the border nor the mouse interaction, why are you using a button in the first place?

Comment: first time i am using PySide. what would you recommend? i just want a corner icon on top of a button basically

Comment: Your question is unclear. I suggest you to [edit] your post and clarify what you mean, possibly by providing an example image of what you want to achieve in comparison to what you actually have.